# GTM how to set up a trigger when message pushed to Data Layer doesn't contain Event variable?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, data

When user clicks on a button a message is sent to the Data Layer, with the relevant information, however it doesn't contain `Event`

To set up a GTM trigger to fire on custom events I need to specify an Event name.

Is there a default name I can use? Or is there any other GTM trigger I should consider instead?

Attached is a screenshot of what the message looks like using DataSlayer chrome extension.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I have an idea. It's possible to create Cutom Data Layer Variable and use that as your trigger. In this case you create a trigger which fiers on all Events with regex like this: .* and then additional check your custom variable. To help you create that variable, can you please add screenshot from your GTM Preview window, under the tab Data Layers and Current values of the Data Layer after triggering the Data Layer? There should be all Data Layers in one. What I want to see is - process: "quote"

Comment: Additionally, enable ckick All Elements trigger, but do not add anywhere. Maybe You can use that + custom variable.

Comment: Another option is creat an event by updating your HTML as in this sample: `<a href="#" name="button1" onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'button1-click'});" >Button 1</a>` if you can't update HTML, then I would belive, that you can use click event. Try and see does it change anything.

Comment: Thanks I will try to implement your first suggestion. The info in the GTM Preview window is the same as the screenshot provided.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. I have created the generic trigger of type Custom Event with regex .*, but it is not activated when the message is sent in the data layer.

Comment: When you push the datalayer? On click or after a response from a server, something like a success that the quote sent? Probably, later will write some more detailed answer.

Comment: @gintsg the data layer message is pushed on a click

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can by using HTML data attributes. When adding them to you HTML Markup you can automatically trigger events.

Also, you can try the CSS-selectors option. https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/matches-css-selector-operator-in-gtm-triggers/

I love this solution, but it comes with a downside: GTM is very picky what item you did click. So I created a jQuery script to look for the closest.

```
function(){
  var one = jQuery({{Click Element}}).closest('[html data attribute here]').attr("html data attribute here ");
  return one;
}
```

Does work like 99%. Of course not when JS is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to trigger a tag on a custom event from the data layer if the `Event` name is not in the object pushed in the data layer.

An alternative is to set up a trigger using Element id or Element class.